# iPhone 6 Simulator not showing correct image

Tags: ios, xcode6, iphone-6

iPhone 6 simulator shows "bg@2x.png" image instead of "bg-667h@2x.png"
iPhone 6+ simulator is showing "bg@3x.png" image which is correct. Don't know whats the issue with iPhone6.
I have also added splash image for iPhone 6 "Default-667h@2x.png".

Answer (score 0):

You need to have same prefix before `@` in the filenames for displaying them on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+. E.g. if `bg2014@3x.png` was used for iPhone 6+, use `bg2014@2x.png` for iPhone 6, with respective resolution of course.

Comment: All images for iPhone 4,5,6 and 6+ have same name but with different suffix.
like name of image for different phones are
iPhone 3        "bg.png",
iPhone 4        "bg@2x.png",
iPhone 5,5s     "bg-568h@2x.png",
iPhone 6        "bg-667h@2x.png", 
iPhone 6+       "bg@3x.png",

Comment: rename `bg-667h@2x.png` to `bg-i6@2x.png` and `bg@3x.png` to `bg-i6@3x`. Let's see how that turns out on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+

Comment: no still loading "bg@2x.png". not loading image for iPhone 6. its working fine for iPhone 6+ with "bg@3x.png".

Comment: did you not rename `bg@3x.png` to `bg-i6@3x`? Clean your project (`Product -> Clean`) and then build.

Comment: I have tried renaming but no luck. i have just checked the width and height of UIScreen for iPhone 6 Simulator and it gives me width=375 and height=667

Comment: Are these files added to the `Images.xcassets`?

Comment: Launch images and icons are added in Images.xcassets. If i check self.view.frame.siz.width in iPhone 6 Simulator it gives me 320. I have no idea why its behaving like that.

Comment: You need to additionally add Launch File for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus support. As [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1), `You use a launch XIB or storyboard file to indicate that your app runs on iPhone 6 Plus or iPhone 6. `

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 6 is Default-375w-667h@2x.png when you don't want to use the Info.plist